# How to play multiple videos simultaneously in a single video view ? or any other ways to do it?

Tags: android, android-videoview

*Here is the code that I've been working on and it only plays a video, I need to play multiple video in a single video view. Or any idea how to this other way ?*

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                // list of mp4 files
                fileNameList = getFileListfromSDCard();

                final VideoView mVideoView2 = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);

                // as of now it plays single video and repeat it over and over again
                String uriPath2 = secStore+"/Videos/test.mp4";
                Uri uri2 = Uri.parse(uriPath2);
                mVideoView2.setVideoURI(uri2);

                mVideoView2.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion( MediaPlayer mp ) {

                        mVideoView2.start();

                    }
                });

                mVideoView2.start();

                MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
                mc.setMediaPlayer(mVideoView2);
                mVideoView2.setMediaController(mc);
      }
```

Comment: I think single video view can not support. You can use multiple video view with many fragments on an activity.

Comment: Try adding these before  mVideoView2.start(); in onCompletion        uriPath2 = secStore+"/Videos/test2.mp4";
                    uri2 = Uri.parse(uriPath2);
                    mVideoView2.setVideoURI(uri2);

Comment: @NougatLover thanks dude, works like a charm!, next question is am I doing this right ? or what better way to make this kind of things ? like how fragments work in this kind of things ?

Comment: I will add it as an answer. Please accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding these before mVideoView2.start(); in onCompletion

uriPath2 = secStore+"/Videos/test2.mp4";

uri2 = Uri.parse(uriPath2);

mVideoView2.setVideoURI(uri2);